# Given algorithm, Whats the time complexity of it?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms

Given algorithm:

[image]

The inner loop is:

[image]

And the outer loop is: $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} * n$  but in the answer is says that I don't need to multiply it by $n$. Can anyone explain why the series is **enough** for the two outer *for* loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outer loop complexity:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^i1=\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The innermost loop takes $O(\log \log n)$ time. You seem to understand that already. Now the outer two loops perform the innermost loop $O(n^2)$ times, as you can check by computing $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Thus the whole thing takes $O(n^2 \log \log n)$ time.